# Getting data from Database using n number of times

Tags: sql, exacttarget

I have a requirement wherein I have to query a database for the following condition.

> Database [Report Pull] has let us say 2 columns
>   CustomerID   ReportDt

I have have to find all the customers who have not have a record in last 30 days but have a record exactly (today - 30 ) among other conditions.

```
Select Condition on [Report Pull] PR
and cast(PR.ReportDt as Date) = cast(getdate()-30 as date)
and not exists (
                select   PR2.*
                from [Report Pull] PR2
                where 1=1
                and cast(PR2.ReportDt as Date) > cast(getdate()-30 as date)
                and PR2.CustomerId = PR.CustomerId
)
```

Now i want to pull customers such that

```
cast(getdate()-30 as date) is mod30 = 0
AND at the same time
cast(PR2.ReportDt as Date) > cast(getdate()-30 as date)

Next 
cast(getdate()-60 as date) is mod30 = 0
AND at the same time
cast(PR2.ReportDt as Date) > cast(getdate()-60 as date)
that is no report pulled in last 60 days
```

and so on for every 30 days. This is because the db can have multiple records of report pull.
I know it is a bit confusing, but please help me. :)

Please note we cannot declare any variable in SQL. The DB is Salesforce Marketing CLoud aka ExactTarget

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on what you are trying to do, but I think you can accomplish this with a single pass of the table (without a self-join).  I'm not saying self-joins are bad, mind you.

Consider this:

```
select
  CustomerID,
  max (case when cast(ReportDt as Date)=cast(getdate()-30 as date) then 1 else 0 end) EQ30,
  max (case when cast(ReportDt as Date)>cast(getdate()-30 as date) then 1 else 0 end) GT30,
  max (case when cast(ReportDt as Date)=cast(getdate()-60 as date) then 1 else 0 end) EQ60,
  max (case when cast(ReportDt as Date)>cast(getdate()-60 as date) then 1 else 0 end) GT60
from
  [Report Pull]
group by
  CustomerID
```

It should result in a dataset that says:

```
Customer ID      30 Days ago?   Last 30 Days    60 Days ago?    Last 60 days
-----------      ------------   ------------    ------------    ------------
```

Where 1 = true and 0 = false.  From here, I think it would be pretty easy to scale this to other timeframes and evaluate customer-by-customer what category they are in.

Again, I'm not sure what you want for your final output, but hopefully this is a concept that will lend to it.